# I get blue screen when my computer restarts after installing video card drivers

Tags: graphics-card

I have a BFG GTX 260 video card, when I turn it on in normal mode it show blue screen but when I turn it on in safe mode it works fine, my motherboard (MSI K9N2 Diamond) has 3 PCI-Ex slots I tried all of them but it still crashes.

Something really strange is that if I uninstall the video drivers and plug the video card it will work fine but after windows automaticly downloads and installs the video dirvers and I restart my computer it crashes and show the blue screen.  I even formatted my hard disk and installed windows 7 and also windows 8 but its still not working....could it be that my video card is damaged?

Comment: If this happens across multiple installations of Windows its not a driver problem which means the card is either not getting enough power or you have some other hardware problem.

Comment: Could try downloading the drivers your manufacturer website yourself. If this doesn't work you might very well have a hardware issue. Try the card in another computer and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: Well I havent changed my hardaware its been the same for 3 years and this is happening since 3 months ago....I have also downloaded and installed the video drivers from the manufacturer website and same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

If it worked for 3 years and started displaying this behavior accross multiple Windows installations, and multiple drivers, then yes the graphics card is likely faulty. I am assuming that when you uninstall the drivers, it is reverting to the Standard VGA driver that does not use the card to its full potential.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download an older version of the driver from nvidia.

If it still does not work, try to reinstall windows from scratch. (save data and format disk)

If it still does not work, GIYF : look for bugs alike.

If it still does not work, try another OS (Linux on Live CD ?)

If it still does not work, your graphic card is probably dead.

BTW : without changing anything on your hardware, dust may prevent heat dissipation. Check the dust in your computer and do some vacuum cleaning.

Vibrations may move the cables : check every connection.

The power supply may also be faulty if it is cheap.